# Check Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\cdot\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to check the convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$
1) I can check the limit of the positive series and find that its equal to $0$.
after that I need to check more things? because monotonic decreasing its not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply the Alternating Series Test, it is sufficient if the absolute values are  monotonically decreasing **after a while.** And they are, we don't even have to wait long.

Comment: its start to decrease only after 2, how I can show that it monotonically decreasing?

Comment: If there **exists** an $N$ such that the terms are monotonically decreasing in absolute value after $N$, and alternating in sign after $N$ (and of course going to $0$) then the series converges. The first million terms don't matter for convergence/divergence.

Comment: I can make derivative of it? and its fine?

Comment: It is fine, in general to decide convergence or divergence of *any* series, we can disregard as many initial terms as we wish.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx} = \cos(\frac{\pi}{n})*(-\frac{\pi}{n^2})$$ this is the derivative, so you say that I dont care about the first terms, and I see that when $n$ limits to $\infty$ its negative, so its monotonically decreasing?

Comment: Naturally, you should not *say* the absolute values are monotonically decreasing, because they are not. But you can say they are monotonically decreasing for $n\ge 2$, and that's enough.

Comment: It you wish to use the derivative, fine, but if is clear that if $a$ and $b$ are between $0$ and $\pi/2$, and $a\lt b$, then $\sin a \lt \sin b$.  If you *really* want to use the derivative, if $n\ge 3$ the derivative is negative, since $\cos$ is positive.

Comment: There is another way to check if it convergence?

Comment: There are always other ways, but this "after a while" version of the Alternating Series Test is by far the easiest. We do not have absolute convergence, the terms don't go down fast enough. One could estimate the sum of two adjacent terms, but it would involve some work.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})=\frac{\pi}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^3})$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=-\ln(2)=O(1)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})=O(1)$$

Answer (score 0):

> This Problem can also be done using Dirchlet's Test if we let $\{a_k\}$=$\{(-1)^k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$=$\{\sin \frac{\pi}{n}\}$.Then observe that sequence of partial sum for $\{a_k\}$ is bounded and sequence $\{b_k\}$ is non-negative and monotone decreasing for $n\ge 2$ with $b_k\to 0$. Then $\sum a_kb_k$ converges by Dirchlet's Test

Comment: Leibniz's Test is an easy, pretty direct  outcome of Dirichlet's test, so if we already have the former what would we want the latter for?