# Check Convergence of $\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}(-1)^n*\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to check the convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}(-1)^n*\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}\right)$$
what I did is:
$$\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}(-1)^n*\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{n+1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1}}$$
now what is the best way to check it? from all the comparison tests?

1) I can say that its $>\frac{1}{n}$ and if I`m not see it directly what I need to do?

thanks!

Comment: Since you have an alternating series ... I'd suggest the alternating series test, just like in your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435839/check-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-1n-cdot-sin-frac-pin). The monotonic convergence is immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use Alternative Series Test, Here the sequence $a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}$ is  decreasing with $a_n\to 0$

Comment: what about leibniz test? so it will convergence with condition?

Comment: Alternative series test and Leibniz test are same !